# Watch for project files also

Tags: scala, sbt

I use `sbt` in the following fashion: I run `~ test:compile` in sbt and then work in IDE, watching occasionaly if the project still compiles, because the IDE's presentation compiler tends to be buggy. When I `git pull` some code, there might be changes in the `project/` files, so I want to have reload. Is there a way, how to watch both source files and project files, so when there is change in project files, I actually get the update?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually can't use `~ <task>` and have it rebuild the project itself right now, because `~ <task>` needs to read the build definition itself to determine:

1. What source files to watch
2. How to run the task.

What you're doing is altering the config whe project/ changes.   This requires a full `reload` or `reboot` of sbt to pull in the new configuration.

So, as of sbt 0.13, this isn't possible.  You *can* have it so it will rebuild your source code when `project/` changes, but without rebuilding the build definition, not much help.

You could create a new sbt prompt, or task, that when run could check to see if source files in project/ are updated and issue a warning/error so you know to reboot.  That's probably the best option right now.

Comment: Is it possible to watch the project folder for change and let SBT shutdown gracefully?

Answer (score 7):

As jsuereth explained this isn't a task SBT can handle in 1 instance. What's required is a reboot of SBT to abort the watching process and reload it's own configuration.

The following Scala script does exactly this, it uses Java NIO WatchService and Scala Process to monitor a path and restart a process. The code should be fairly simple to understand:

```
#!/usr/bin/env scala

import java.nio.file._
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
import scala.sys.process._

val file = Paths.get(args(0))
val cmd = args(1)
val watcher = FileSystems.getDefault.newWatchService

file.register(
  watcher, 
  StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE,
  StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY,
  StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_DELETE
)

def exec = cmd run true

@scala.annotation.tailrec
def watch(proc: Process): Unit = {
  val key = watcher.take
  val events = key.pollEvents

  val newProc = 
    if (!events.isEmpty) {
      proc.destroy()
      exec
    } else proc

  if (key.reset) watch(newProc)
  else println("aborted")
}

watch(exec)
```

Usage in your sbt dir would be:

```
watchr.scala project/ "sbt ~ test:compile"
```

If anything is unclear don't hesitate to ask, of course any scripting language could be used to implement this behavior.