# How do you write a Scala script that will react to file changes

Tags: scala

I would like to change the following batch script to Scala (just for fun), however, the script must keep running and listen for changes to the *.mkd files. If any file is changed, then the script should re-generate the affected doc. File IO has always been my Achilles heel...

```
#!/bin/sh
for file in *.mkd
do
  pandoc --number-sections $file -o "${file%%.*}.pdf"
done
```

Any ideas around a good approach to this will be appreciated.

Comment: Use a Java [`WatchService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html)

Comment: Thanks Boris. It seems that's the best way to go.

Answer (score 5):

The following code, taken from my answer on: [Watch for project files also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19537311/watch-for-project-files-also/19558452#19558452) can watch a directory and execute a specific command:

```
#!/usr/bin/env scala

import java.nio.file._
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
import scala.sys.process._

val file = Paths.get(args(0))
val cmd = args(1)
val watcher = FileSystems.getDefault.newWatchService

file.register(
  watcher, 
  StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE,
  StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY,
  StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_DELETE
)

def exec = cmd run true

@scala.annotation.tailrec
def watch(proc: Process): Unit = {
  val key = watcher.take
  val events = key.pollEvents

  val newProc = 
    if (!events.isEmpty) {
      proc.destroy()
      exec
    } else proc

  if (key.reset) watch(newProc)
  else println("aborted")
}

watch(exec)
```

Usage:

```
watchr.scala markdownFolder/ "echo \"Something changed!\""
```

Extensions have to be made to the script to inject file names into the command. As of now this snippet should just be regarded as a building block for the actual answer.

Modifying the script to incorporate the *.mkd wildcards would be non-trivial as you'd have to manually search for the files and register a watch on all of them. Re-using the script above and placing all files in a directory has the added advantage of picking up new files when they are created.

As you can see it gets pretty big and messy pretty quick just relying on Scala & Java APIs, you would be better of relying on alternative libraries or just sticking to bash while using INotify.

Comment: Thanks Bob, it almost works. However, the parameter gets lost somewhere. If you did `whatchr.scala folder/ "echo $file"` then it would just echo empty lines, and much more that just the file changes. Thanks for the help so far ;-)

Comment: Oops, you're right that was pretty stupid of me, I'll modify the answer explaining the additional changes that need to be made. The code at the moment should just be used as an example of WatchService in Scala.

Comment: there is also [schwatcher](https://github.com/lloydmeta/schwatcher) projects which wraps a WatchService API in a more human-usable abstraction.