# How can I trigger a Kafka Producer everytime a new file is added to the directory?

Tags: scala, triggers, apache-kafka, producer-consumer

I have a Kafka streaming producer (in scala) that extracts data from all files in a directory, and publishes their content into a topic. That content is then processed by the consumer.

Now I am executing both producer and consumer (both in scala) manually through shell, but how can I make something as to trigger both Kafka producer and consumer to execute automatically everytime a file is added to the directory the producer is retrieving files from? 
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you write a Scala script that will react to file changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19806957/how-do-you-write-a-scala-script-that-will-react-to-file-changes)

Answer (score 1):

You may be better off using the Kafka Connect API, which is part of Apache Kafka. [kafka-connect-spooldir](https://github.com/jcustenborder/kafka-connect-spooldir) is a connector which will monitor a folder and ingest any new files into a Kafka topic, from where you can then do further processing on it if you want.